# Modrewrite to lighttpd

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, lighttpd

I've the following .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html /$1.php
RewriteRule ^scss/([^/]*)\.css$ /showcss.php?css=$1 [L]
```

how can I convert it to lighttpd?

Answer (score 0):

See the lighttpd tutorial for [Migrating from Apache](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/wiki/1/MigratingFromApache). There isn't a nice 1-to-1 mapping of rewrite rules from apache to lighttpd, but those should be pretty straightforward. See if this works for you (may require a little regex tweaking):

```
url.rewrite-once = ( "^/([^/]*)\.html" => "/$1.php", 
                     "^/scss/([^/]*)\.css$" => "/showcss.php?css=$1")
```